# Hi - I am creating a new table that needs 72 columns named mycount-1 to mycount-72 all of type integer

Tags: postgresql

Rather than  explicitly state each column name in the initial create I am thinking that I should be able to have a loop with an incremental value which concatenates to "mycount-" then feeds into add column command. Alternatively could this be achieved through a generate-series command.

I have no idea what is or what's best practice to achieve this and I cant find any examples that do this.

if you could point me in the right direction of a thread that helps or some code that would be wonderful.

Comment: Having "numbered columns" is a huge red flag in database design. It's almost always better done by creating the corresponding number of _rows_

Comment: If you think you need a 72 column wide table then you probably need to rethink your design.

Comment: Just to give some color to the previous comment and because you are a new contributor to the site, @a_horse_with_no_name is in the top 3 contributors, perhaps even the top one, for postgresql. Whatever he says, which I happen to agree with, you really should heed it.

Comment: I think your design have normalization concerns. because you can simply normalize the design by separating the table and adding FK relationship on it.

Comment: I am creating a temporary table to create a CSV report. The 72 columns are to contain the count of sales per calendar month for the last 6 years of each customer. I could call them YYYY;MM or something more meaningful but the idea  seemed like an easy solution to a quick report. I am intrigued by how psql hangs together and this is a learning curve rather than a production requirement. So it would be great to hear how i can actually make this happen even if not best practice.

Comment: As others have said, your proposed model appears to have design issues. The description sounds like a case of a repeating group, which can be eliminated by modeling the repeated columns as rows in a separate table referencing the first (lookup _third normal form_). Alternatively, the values could be modeled as a column of type `integer[]`. With either approach, check constraints can restrict the number of values.

Comment: Consider using a view instead of a table. If the view takes excessively long to run, then consider using a materialized view. A hybrid approach might work well: create a view to get customer sales by month, use that view to populate a materialized view for prior months, and create another view to be used by the report that creates a union of the prior months from the materialized view and the current month using the first view. Of course, if the view to get customer sales by month runs quickly enough, then only that view will be required.

Comment: Smells like bad design. What will happen if the Marketing Department comes on Monday and says that they need 96 columns now, or 192. Will all your code crash and burn? You better separate the data in multiple tables.

Answer (score 1):

The comments about the questionable design choice should be considered **first**.

That being said, you can indeed create such table in a generic statement, making use of `psql` `\gexec` utility.

The idea is to create a string containing the command to be executed, and to run it by appending `\gexec` after the query.

Since you have multiple column, you can at the same time call `generate_series` and concatenating its output with the column name into a single row.

```
SELECT 'create table test_rec (id integer, ' || string_agg('mycount_' || i || ' integer',', ') ||');'
FROM generate_series(1,5) g(i);\gexec
```

On the other hand, I personally find it more efficient for these kind of tasks to open Excel or alike, drag a number list, concatenate with a fixed text, copy-paste-done.

Comment: thank you to everyone the last post by JGH did exactly what i was trying to achieve. big thank you JHG

Comment: As  my design for a temporary table has not been best practice it would be great to progress this to what my thoughts are as an improved column naming convention.

Comment: As  my design for a temporary table has not been best practice it would be great to progress this to what my thoughts are as an improved column naming convention. would it be possible  for the column to be named 2023-NN where the first column is this  current month and the following columns descend for NN months?